# Xamarin android import library

Tags: android, xamarin

In java can add:

```
import com.runjva.sourceforge.jsocks.protocol.ProxyServer;
import com.runjva.sourceforge.jsocks.server.ServerAuthenticatorNone;
```

but how I can do it in my xamarin android app?

Comment: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/binding-a-java-library/

Comment: You can use it to socket operations "System.Net"

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Java Bindings Library to use any AAR or JAR file in Xamarin for Android. Note that, due to some differences between C# and Java, it's possible that you'll have to do a little bit of manual mapping (there's an XML format provided for that). Using this, the compiler will take care of all the JNI bindings and other "plumbing" for you; it'll even convert naming conventions (e.g. prefix interface names with "I").

Answer (score 0):

Are you using xamarin in visual studio ? if yes then you can simply go to tools and then nuget package manager and install packages.More over you can also search packages on nuget.org its the best site

Answer (score 0):

First thing, check nuget if what you look is already there.

If it is not there, use this VS extension:
https://github.com/EgorBo/Xamarin.GradleBindings

Download the extension from here:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=EgorBogatov.XamarinGradleBindings

Then after adding the extension to Visual Studio, right click on your reference and then you will see

> Add Dependency via gradle

1. Put the dependency id.
2. Choose the dependencies you need and download them.
3. **DONT FORGET** to put the dependency into your **Jar folder** (because you might the produced member in your reference dll).
4. You might need to fix the problems by adding some lines in the **metadata.xml***.
5. If you still don't get any members, you can extract the classes.jar file from the .aar file then rename it to the package file and follow the .jar binding instructions:

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/binding-a-java-library/binding-a-jar/

*Refer to binding troubleshooting to fix any issue you face (most of the binding needs that step of fixing the metadata.xml): https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/binding-a-java-library/troubleshooting-bindings/ )